# how to identify inline level `<code>` vs. block level `<code>` generated by the `markdown` command

Tags: html, css, markdown

I'm trying to generate web pages from markdown files.  This example produces the desired visual presentation of a web page:

`header.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
code {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 125%;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
p:nth-of-type(1) code {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  color: red;
}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
```

`body.md`

````
Assuming you have the IP `1.1.1.1` or `2.2.2.2`, then execute the following:

```
echo "hello world";
echo "another command here";
echo "you are done";
```
````

`footer.html`

```
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the commands:

```
apt-get install markdown;
markdown body.md > body.html;
cat header.html body.html footer.html > index.html;
```

I see this in my web browser:

[image]

**This is exactly what I want to see!**

However, I want to delete the `p:nth-of-type(1) code` rule because I do not want to write custom CSS selectors to target every single inline `<code>` block.  I have thousands of pages of markdown documents to convert to html.  Manually going through page by page to pick out which `<code>` block is inline and which is a block level element is too time consuming.

Is there an easier way to either

a) write a CSS selector that targets `p>code` if and only if the `p` has one and only one child element and that one child element is of element type `code`

or b) a way to tell the `markdown` command to add a css class to `<code>` element

or c) something completely different to let me write a generic css rule to target inline code elements vs block level code elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a) write a CSS selector that targets p>code if and only if the p has one and only one child element and that one child element is of element type code

What you are looking for is the pseudo-class [`:only-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child)

Your desired selector is simply `p > code:only-child`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that code blocks are wrapped with `<pre><code>` tags, while inline code spans are only wrapped in `code` tags. You can use this in your CSS to differentiate:

```css
code {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  color: red;
}
pre code {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 125%;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1em 0;
  color: black;
}
```

Note that the `code` style needs to be defined first as that applies to all `<code>` tags, including the block. Then in the block styles, you need to override those where appropriate. Therefore, I have added a color to revert the color in the blocks only.

Also, you don't need the `white-space: pre;` as the `<pre>` tag gives you that by default. Therefore, I removed it.